# ORACLE: ORA-02013: missing CONNECT keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When executing this Script using SQL Developer 4.0 against a Oracle 11.2 Express database

```
ALTER USER TMS QUOTA 100M ON TDM
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO TMS
```

I get a the following error:

```
ORA-02013: missing CONNECT keyword
02013. 00000 -  "missing CONNECT keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Upfront I did connect to localhost / xe.

I also tried

```
CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA
```

and entered my password.

`CREATE TABLE` statements fail with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to execute two commands as one. Put a semicolon at the end of each of them and it will work:

```
ALTER USER TMS QUOTA 100M ON TDM;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO TMS;
```

Check the possibilites of the ALTER USER command here: [ALTER USER - Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm)